# gzip pickle dump save multiple items

Tags: python, gzip, pickle

I am having some trouble using gzip and pickle . Basically I have the following code where I try to save a random dataset using gzip and pickle.dump

```py
import pickle
import gzip
import torch
import numpy as np

with gzip.open('test.pt', "wb") as f:
    for d in range(50):
        a = np.random.rand(3,2).astype(np.float32)
        aa = torch.from_numpy(a)
        pickle.dump({'name': str(d), 'person': 'test', 'text1':'blah', 
                    'text2': 'blah', 'data': aa}, f)        

with gzip.open('test.pt', "rb") as f:
    data4 = pickle.load(f)
print(data4)
```

Prints only the first element, why?

I was expecting the output of the line above to be:

```
[{'name': '0', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah',
  'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],
                  [0.0728, 0.6768],
                  [0.9147, 0.2786]])},
  {'name': '1', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah',
   'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],
                   [0.0728, 0.6768],
                   [0.9147, 0.2786]])},
  {'name': '2', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah',
   'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],
                   [0.0728, 0.6768],
                   [0.9147, 0.2786]])},
  ...,
  {'name': '49', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah',
   'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],
                   [0.0728, 0.6768],
                   [0.9147, 0.2786]])}]
```

```py
for d in data4:
    print(d)

# prints: name, person, text1, text2, data, why ???**
```

I was excepting the output to be:

```py
{'name': '0', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah', 'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],[0.0728, 0.6768],[0.9147, 0.2786]])}
{'name': '1', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah', 'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],[0.0728, 0.6768],[0.9147, 0.2786]])}
{'name': '2', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah', 'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],[0.0728, 0.6768],[0.9147, 0.2786]])}
...
{'name': '49', 'person': 'test', 'text1': 'blah', 'text2': 'blah', 'data': tensor([[0.8789, 0.4588],[0.0728, 0.6768],[0.9147, 0.2786]])}
```

When I do,

```py
for d in data4:
    print(d['name'])
```

I get:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-13370f7fdb11> in <module>
22 
23 for d in data4:
---> 24     print(d['name'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers**
```

And lastly don't really understood why I can't access using `d['name']`

Any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Pickle is a self contained format.  You can't simply concatenate different pickle objects and have the decoder make sense of the result.  If you want to write multiple objects to the file and then read them latter, you need to add some details to the file itself so you'll know how to load the individual objects.

One simple way to accomplish this is to add lengths to the file to know how big each object is:

```
import pickle
import gzip
import torch
import numpy as np
import struct

with gzip.open('test.pt', "wb") as f:
    for d in range(50):
        a = np.random.rand(3,2).astype(np.float32)
        aa = torch.from_numpy(a)
        temp = pickle.dumps({'name': str(d), 'person': 'test', 'text1':'blah', 
                    'text2': 'blah', 'data': aa})
        f.write(struct.pack("L", len(temp)))
        f.write(temp)

data4 = []
with gzip.open('test.pt', "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data_length = f.read(4)
        if len(data_length) == 0:
            # No more data
            break
        data_length = struct.unpack("L", data_length)[0]
        data4.append(pickle.loads(f.read(data_length)))
print(data4)
```

Alternatively, and much more directly, you could just save the list in one go:

```
data = []
for d in range(50):
    a = np.random.rand(3,2).astype(np.float32)
    aa = torch.from_numpy(a)
    data.append({'name': str(d), 'person': 'test', 'text1':'blah', 
                'text2': 'blah', 'data': aa})
with gzip.open('test.pt', "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

data4 = []
with gzip.open('test.pt', "rb") as f:
    data4 = pickle.load(f)
print(data4)
```